# Implement custom file picker dialog in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have bottomsheet dialog for choosing file but, i don't know how to implement file picker in it, i want to make as in screenshot below.I have been looking for answer but i found only some libraries but it is simple dialog not bottomsheet.

[image: bottomsheet dialog image]

Please Help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simple Storage's file picker. It supports scoped storage.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val storageHelper = SimpleStorageHelper(this)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    storageHelper.onFolderSelected = { requestCode, folder ->
        // do stuff
    }
    storageHelper.onFileSelected = { requestCode, file ->
        // do stuff
    }

    btnOpenFolderPicker.setOnClickListener { storageHelper.openFolderPicker() }
    btnOpenFilePicker.setOnClickListener { storageHelper.openFilePicker() }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    storageHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    storageHelper.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
}
```

}